# How do I organize nested classes to be references in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, items

So I'm working on a game and I'd like some recommendations for how to sort items for easy, legible, coding reference in Unity. I know my current method is flawed, and really I'd just like some guidance.

So what I'm doing is using classes to separate item categories and their items.
For example, here's an idea of a setup for a script :

```
public class Items {
    public class Equipment {
        public class Weapons {
            public Item Sword = new Item();
            Sword.name = "Sword";
            Sword.cost = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

then a basic Item class for example

```
public class Item {
    public string name;
    public int cost;
}
```

I can tell this is terrible practice, especially based on the problems I've been having, but I like the idea of using a reference like Items.Equipment.Weapons.Sword and I've grown accustomed to using that from an API I previously used.

I'm open to completely changing everything, I just want some tips. Thanks.

I guess my main question is (was), what's the best way to organize nested classes so they can be references from other scripts easily?

The answer I found was that instead of nesting classes, in my case, it's better to use namespaces to separate items into categories. Thanks a million.

Comment: Why not use [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) or is that not possible in Unity?

Comment: What result are you looking for?  Is there a specific reason that you want each item to be its own unique class?  Do you want a way to make this work within your nested class example, or do you want overall recommendations?

Comment: Yeah I've had some difficulties using it in Unity. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: The nested classes are just for organization to get to the items, for now anyways. So eventually I'd like to be able to use these items. I'd like to be able to do something like Player.Inventory.addItem(Items.Equipment.Weapons.Sword);

Comment: You can use c# properties to achieve what you want.

Comment: Based on your example, namespaces sound like the right answer ([and they are supported by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Namespaces.html)). That said, I think your question is likely to be flagged for being "too broad" or "opinion-based." Can you edit to focus on the specific difficulties you've had with nested classes and/or namespaces?

Comment: namespaces was the solution, I was just using them inappropriately. Namespace comes before the class, and requires a class inside of them for the body. I didn't get that. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using ScriptableObjects to create your items, armor, and weapons.  [You'll have to spend an hour or two learning them,](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) but I think you'll be much happier with your design if you go that route.

Think of a ScriptableObject as a set of properties (item name, cost, attack power, defense power, etc.).  For each item you have in your game, you create an instance of a ScriptableObject.  Those ScriptableObject instances then become assets in your Unity project, just like a prefab or a sprite.  That means you can drag them around in your project, and assign them to the fields on your MonoBehaviours.  That'll result in you being able to assign equipment to a character by dragging it from your Project view into the Inspector.

Here's an example of how it'll look

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public string name;
    public int cost;
    public Sprite image;
}
```

**Equipment.cs**

```
public class Equipment : Item
{
    public Slots slot;
}

public enum Slots
{
    Body,
    DoubleHanded,
    Hands,
    Head,
    Feet,
    Legs,
    LeftHand,
    RightHand
}
```

**Weapon.cs**

```
// CreateAssetMenu is what lets you create an instance of a Weapon in your Project
// view.  Make a folder for your weapons, then right click inside that folder (in the 
// Unity project view) and there should be a menu option for Equipment -> Create Weapon
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Equipment/Create Weapon")]
public class Weapon : Equipment
{
    public int attackPower;    
    public int attackSpeed;
    public WeaponTypes weaponType;
}

public enum WeaponTypes
{
    Axe,
    Bow,
    Sword
}
```

**Armor.cs**

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Equipment/Create Armor")]
public class Armor : Equipment
{
    public int defensePower;
}
```

Now create a bunch of weapons and armor in your project.

[image]

One thing that makes ScriptableObjects nice is you can edit them in your Inspector, rather than having to do it through code (although you can do that too).

[image]

Now on your "character" MonoBehaviour, add some properties for that character's equipment.

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Armor bodyArmor;
    public Armor headArmor;
    public Weapon weapon;
}
```

Now you can assign your weapons and armor to your character in the Inspector

[image]

You'll probably want something more customized to your needs than my example, but those are the basics.  I recommend spending some time looking at ScriptableObjects.  Read the Unity docs I linked earlier, or watch some videos on YouTube.

One of Unity's strengths is that it lets you do a lot of design and configuration through the editor rather than through code, and ScriptableObjects reinforce that.

Comment: This is amazing. Exactly what I needed! I feel this is going to help me so much. Thank you!